# Can't open jupyter notebook at all

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel, dataspell, jupyter-nbclassic

Last weeks everything was ok. But all of a sudden I can't run jupyter notebook (if i run it from the start menu it wont open / if i run it from anaconda navigator or dataspell it wont run and give me the following error:

> Jupyter server process exited with code 1 Traceback (most recent call
> last): File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py",
> line 235, in _resolve_classes klass = self._resolve_string(klass)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py",
> line 2028, in _resolve_string return import_item(string)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py",
> line 31, in import_item module = **import**(package, fromlist=[obj])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'jupyter_server.contents'  During handling of the above
> exception, another exception occurred:  Traceback (most recent call
> last): File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line
> 10, in   sys.exit(main()) ^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py",
> line 280, in launch_instance super().launch_instance(argv=argv,
> **kwargs) File "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> line 1051, in launch_instance app = cls.instance(**kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py",
> line 581, in instance inst = cls(*args, **kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py",
> line 1313, in **new** inst.setup_instance(*args, **kwargs) File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py",
> line 1356, in setup_instance super(HasTraits,
> self).setup_instance(*args, **kwargs) File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py",
> line 1332, in setup_instance init(self) File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py",
> line 226, in instance_init self._resolve_classes() File
> "C:\Users\SOL-1\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\notebook\traittypes.py",
> line 238, in _resolve_classes warn(f"{klass} is not importable. Is it
> installed?", ImportWarning) TypeError: warn() missing 1 required
> keyword-only argument: 'stacklevel' )

[Screenshot of the error when I try to run a simple code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtMWO.png)

**I reinstalled anaconda navigator (anaconda3), jupyter notebook, python.
It doesnt work.** Last weeks when it worked I just opened jupyter notebook from the start menu and then it opened in my browser as a localhost (it worked fine).
If I try to do that now it just opens a cmd window and it shows a big text but closes very quickly as I cant see the text in it.
I am currently enrolled in IBM Data Science Professional Certificate and I'm trying to use it like I used it in the previous courses but now it won't work.

Comment: Have you activated the anaconda environment that you installed jupyter in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may be dealing with an error similar to this Github issue post: https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/24436. Looks like the solution solved the error for multiple people.

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked!!! (pip uninstall traitlets
pip install traitlets==5.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too. The solution is to update jupyter to the latest version (7.0.x).

Do:

```
conda update notebook
```